# Radius of convergence of a power series: seemingly two different approaches

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

From a textbook, I have learned that the radius of convergence of a power series, i.e., $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n (x - a)^n$, can be obtained from the limit (if it exists): $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{c_n}{c_{n + 1}}|$. However, in other places, people have used the following limit to obtain the radius of convergence: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$. How are these two related to each other?

Comment: The formula you learned is a shorthand for the ratio test: If $\vert x\vert$ is smaller than that limit, then the series converges due to the ratio test. The other formula does the same for the root test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ratio test**: If $$\limsup|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\le 1  ~~as ~n\to \infty$$
Then the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

**Root test**: If
$$\limsup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \le 1~~~as ~n\to \infty$$
Then the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

The ratio test is frequently easier to apply than the root test, since it is usually easier to compute ratios than $n^{th}$ root. More precisely ,the root test is stronger than the ratio test: there are cases in which the root test shows convergence but the ratio test does not.

Consider the series $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\dots$$.

Can you prove the below theorem?

**Theorem** For any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive numbers,
$$\limsup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq lim\operatorname{sup}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}~~~~as~~n\to \infty$$

If you prove this then you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: My pleasure ${}{}{}$

Comment: You can use \limsup for $\limsup$ instead of what you were doing before. I've edited your post with this.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Very clarifying reasoning and example, thank you very much. Do you know more examples where the root test shows convergence but the ratio test does not?

Answer (score 0):

First one is D'Alembert test, second Cauchy. It's known, that if exists first, then exists second and they are equal.

Comment: Thanks for giving this information.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=c_n (x - a)^n$

Ratio test: $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|= |\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}| \cdot |x-a|$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{c_n}{c_{n + 1}}|=R$, then

$$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \to \frac{|x-a|}{R}.$$

Hence $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n (x - a)^n$ converges if $|x-a| <R.$

And $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n (x - a)^n$ diverges if $|x-a| >R.$

Root test: $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}|x-a|$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}=r$, then
$$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \to  \frac{|x-a|}{r}.$$

Hence $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n (x - a)^n$ converges if $|x-a| <r.$

And $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n (x - a)^n$ diverges if $|x-a| >r.$

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer!